# Unpacking list of dictionary elements into pandas data frame

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I am trying to parse my itunes playlist which is in xml format.

Here is the sample xml which i am trying to parse and put the end result in pandas data frame.

```
    <dict>
                <key>Track ID</key><integer>3636</integer>
                <key>Size</key><integer>6661871</integer>
                <key>Total Time</key><integer>211774</integer>
                <key>Track Number</key><integer>4</integer>
                <key>Track Count</key><integer>14</integer>
                <key>Year</key><integer>2007</integer>
                <key>Date Modified</key><date>2008-06-27T15:14:16Z</date>
                <key>Date Added</key><date>2009-07-06T12:03:10Z</date>
                <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>251</integer>
                <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
                <key>Play Count</key><integer>5</integer>
                <key>Play Date</key><integer>3373708724</integer>
                <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2010-11-27T13:18:44Z</date>
                <key>Skip Count</key><integer>3</integer>
                <key>Skip Date</key><date>2015-06-26T14:20:01Z</date>
                <key>Persistent ID</key><string>E966DF081B4B40E1</string>
                <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
                <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>5</integer>
                <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
                <key>Artist</key><string>Fall Out Boy</string>
                <key>Album</key><string>Infinity On High</string>
                <key>Genre</key><string>Rock</string>
                <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
</dict>
```

Following is my python code for parsing the xml

```
from lxml import objectify
import pandas as pd
path = 'C:/Users/username/desktop/itunes.xml'
xml = objectify.parse(open(path))
root = xml.getroot()
tracks = root.getchildren()[0].getchildren()[15]
oddelements=tracks.getchildren()[1::2]
```

The end result "oddelements" object is a list of element dictionaries

Each element dictionary in this list contains the information enclosed in "dict" tag in the sample xml which i have pasted above.

How do i parse this list of element dictionaries and unpack them into pandas data frame for further analysis?

Many thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
root=ET.fromstring('<dict><key>Track ID</key><integer>3636</integer></dict>')
#parsing into a dictionary
d={}
k=''
for t in root:
  if t.tag=='key':
    k=t.text
    continue
  d[k]=t.text
#transforming to a DataFrame
df=pd.DataFrame(d.items(),columns=['key','value'])
print (df)
```

Comment: Thanks Uri. However if i was to go by my way of doing it though lxml package, do u have any ideas about how to unpack key values from list of dictonary elements i.e say if my object was a list containing dictionaries like [ dict 1, dict 2.... dict n]?